# scikits.audiolab not making audible wav file

Tags: python, arrays, audio, numpy, signal-processing

I've got a numpy array of 1's and 0's...something like this:

[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,....]

Anyway, it's an array created by watching where zero crossings happen in an audio wav file...when I implement 
`afile.write_frames(tmp, len(audio_array))`
where tmp is the numpy arrray of 1's and 0's and len(audio_array) is the length of the array, I get nothing in the output.

However, my script does work if I feed in the original audio file...it outputs a file that makes sound, sounds like the original audio file...looks good.
But, for some reason, feeding in 1's and 0's doesn't produce any audio...Why is this?

Comment: what is the data type for the elements of the array?

Comment: Are you trying to create a 16bit audio file (which is the default format) with 0's and 1's only? If yes, then dither has higher amplitude than that...